# FILTER 2 columns into one with NOT(ISBLANK)

Tags: google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query, google-query-language

I have two columns which I want to convert into 1 column, but not showing the blanks.
e.g.

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|      Column 1       |     Column 2     |
|---------------------|------------------|
|       Test1         |      Test2       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|                     |                  |
|---------------------|------------------|
|       Test4         |      Test3       |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

Expected result:

```
|---------------------|
|      Column 1       |
|---------------------|
|       Test1         |
|---------------------|
|       Test2         |
|---------------------|
|       Test3         |
|---------------------|
|       Test4         |
|---------------------|
```

My best bet would be using this formula, but it is not working.

```
=FILTER({E6:G17,E22:G33},NOT(ISBLANK({E6:G17,E22:G33})))
```

Can you guys help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=QUERY({A:A; B:B}, "where Col1 is not null")
```

or:

```
=FILTER({A:A; B:B}, {A:A; B:B}<>"")
```